# Linq2SQL grouping and ungrouping in the same query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Here's a stumper in LINQ to SQL:

```
string p = prefix ?? "";
string d = delimiter ?? "";
var filegroups = from b in folder.GetFiles(data)
                    where b.Uri.StartsWith(p) && b.Uri.CompareTo(marker ?? "") >= 0
                    group b by data.DataContext.GetFileFolder(p, d, b.Uri);
//var folders = from g in filegroups where g.Key.Length > 0 select g;
//var files = from g in filegroups where g.Key.Length == 0 select g;
var files = filegroups.SelectMany(g => g.Key.Length > 0
    ? from b in g.Take(1) select new FilePrefix { Name = g.Key }
    : from b in g select new FilePrefix { Name = b.Uri, Original = b });

var retval = files.Take(maxresults);
```

folders cannot be nested (out of my control) but filenames can contain slashes and whatever so a deeper folder structure can be emulated

**folder.GetFiles** is a simple linq equiv (IOrderedQueryable) to `select * from files where folderid=@folderid order by Uri`

**prefix** is a filter saying return only those files that start with...
**delimiter** is the path delimiter, such as '/'
**marker** is for pagination - starts returning at a specified point

**data.DataContext.GetFileFolder** maps to a sql scalar function: return the whole string up to and including the next delimiter that occurs after the prefix string
`RETURN substring(@uri, 0, charindex(@delimiter, @uri, len(@prefix)) + len(@delimiter))`  That was for troubleshooting - original was a client-side where clause that did map correctly to TSQL.  I had just hoped doing a function would change things in the final graph, but nope.

in the above, filegroups, and the commented out folders, and files, all work as expected

**The goal** is to hit the database just once.  I'd like to, in a single return, show subfolders and files based upon interpretation of the FilePrefix object (folders have a null 'original'        value)

The issue is with the final selectmany throwing "Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL."

I strongly suspect this would work perfectly if it weren't for the TSQL translation, but looking at this logically, why would it not do its database work and then select the FilePrefixes client side as a final step?

It's late ;)  but tomorrow I'll revert to a double tap on the database by slipping a ToList() or something similar somewhere up there to cause that final step to be full client side (kludge).  But if anyone has any insights on how to accomplish this with one database hit (short of writing a stored procedure), I'd love to hear it!!

The downside to the kludge is that the final Take(maxresults) could be expensive if the db hit results in a number of records that far exceeds that.  And the subsequent `Skip(maxresults).Take(1)` that I didn't quote, for marking the next page, would hurt twice as much.

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: webapi cloud storage solution.  the returned fileprefix objects will be expanded to format and serialize a response that doesn't exactly match the linq object layout.  And the prescribed response intermingles folders and files.

folders are being emulated by the grouping, and files within the group are being dropped and not returned (because they are in subfolders).  The files found within the zero length group key are in 'this' folder and are being returned

Comment: and yup, as expected, changing the `filegroups.SelectMany` to `filegroups.AsEnumerable().SelectMany` is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it looks like 2 database hits are necessary.  I started by noticing that the call graph converted the tertiary operator into an IIF which led me to think that IIF, on the sql side, probably doesn't like  subqueries as parameters.

```
string p = prefix ?? "";
string d = delimiter ?? "";
var filegroups = from b in folder.GetFiles(data)
                    where b.Uri.StartsWith(p) && b.Uri.CompareTo(marker ?? "") >= 0
                    group b by data.DataContext.nx_GetFileFolder(p, d, b.Uri);
var folders = from g in filegroups where g.Key.Length > 0 select g.Key;
var files = from b in folder.GetFiles(data)
            where b.Uri.StartsWith(p) && b.Uri.CompareTo(marker ?? "") >= 0
                && data.DataContext.nx_GetFileFolder(p, d, b.Uri).Length == 0
            select b;

folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f).Take(maxresults + 1);
files = files.OrderBy(f => f.Uri).Take(maxresults + 1);

var retval = folders.AsEnumerable().Select(f => new FilePrefix { Name = f })
            .Concat(files.AsEnumerable().Select(f => new FilePrefix { Name = f.Uri, Original = f }))
            .OrderBy(b => b.Name).Take(maxresults + 1);

int count = 0;
foreach (var bp in retval)
{
    if (count++ < maxresults)
        yield return bp;
    else
        newmarker.Name = bp.Name;
}
yield break;
```

a bit less elegant...  I left filegroups and folders, but rewrote the files query to get rid of the group (generated cleaner sql and probably more efficient).

Concat still gave me trouble in this new approach, so I kicked in the AsEnumerable calls, which is the point that breaks this into 2 hits to the database.

I kept maxresults in the sql to limit traffic, so worst case is twice as much data as I want going over the wire.  The +1 is to get the next record so the user can be notified where to start on the next page.  And I used the iterator pattern so I wouldn't have to loop again to get that next record.